# JMenu Mnemonic characters are displayed permanently

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jmenu, mnemonics

I have a little Problem, even though my ALT Key isn't down (the key is not broken, neither is it stuck) it permanently highlights the `JMenu` components (Not just the single menus but also their sub-menu characters) Mnemonic Characters.

Update:

I found out why it happens, it seems to be the L&f. I am currently using Nimbus but if i use the Windows look and feel everything works perfect. So here comes the second question can i somehow change that, i haven't found anything in the nimbus defaults?

MCVE:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class Main
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    try
    {
      for ( final LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels() )
      {
        if ( "Nimbus".equals( info.getName() ) )
        {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel( info.getClassName() );
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    catch ( final Exception exception )
    {
      //UNIMPORTANT
    }
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize( 800, 600 );

    final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    final JMenu testMenu = new JMenu( "testMenu" );
    testMenu.setMnemonic( KeyEvent.VK_T );

    menuBar.add( testMenu );

    frame.setJMenuBar( menuBar );

    frame.setVisible( true );
  }   
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in the comments..

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.